# Android Studio + Gradle old apk is being uploaded to device if filename is changed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle, gradlew

Inside my build.gradle file I have a debug buildType which contains the following:

```
 versionNameSuffix "-" + buildTime()
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                if (!variant.buildType.name.equals("debug")) return;
                def file = variant.outputFile
                variant.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace("unaligned.apk", buildTime() + "-signed.apk"))
            }
```

Now the version name and file name changes work perfectly, exactly as planned. The problem is that each time I run the project so that I can deploy the apk to a USB device, Android Studio doesn't take into account the newly created build. It uploads the older one from the build/apk folder.
For example, if build/apk folder contains build-2013-10-07-1.apk and build-2013-10-07-2.apk, the first one is uploaded, not the 2nd. Any ideas why ? Workarounds, etc. ?

Comment: Forgot to add the fact that I was trying to use a timestamp in the filename like "project-20131009-13:20-signed.apk". I ended up using only the date, not the time part; like "project-20131009-signed.apk". Granted, if you're up till 12:00 AM and make another build at 12:01 AM next day, you get into this problem again, but during the day everything works like a charm and it's way better than just manually renaming the filename after building it, every god damn time.

Comment: I have date in file name and there is the same problem. I have to start a day from clicking on "Sync project with Gradle Files". That solves the problem but only until the next day.

Comment: Yeah I know. When I first wrote the solution, the Android tools team made a sync each day or something like that. Since then, they removed that daily sync, so that's why you need to resync on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the date stamp instead of the time stamp. There still is a problem inside Android Studio in which after a day passes, you need to do a Gradle Sync in order for the new build to be installed, instead of the yesterday's build.